# Getting values from input id using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Assume I have a form

```
<input type="text" id="Rice" onkeyup="get();"value="">
<input type="text" id="Noodles" onkeyup="get();" value="">
<input type="text" id="Chicken" onkeyup="get();" value="">
<input type="text" id="Beef" onkeyup="get();" value="">
```

I'm confused here ..
I need when input value at id="Rice" change into 1, and then create ID+VALUE (Rice 1)

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2Lnmu5ja/

Comment: Two things: 1) where is the JS code? 2) I've read your question multiple times and am still confused what you're trying to do. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make that much sense, you need to explain 
 what you're trying to do and show how you tried to do that.

Comment: @Thijs edited, i hope u can help

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    var idne = this.id;
    var vale = this.value;
    alert(idne + " " + vale);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Rice" value="" placeholder="rice"><br>
<input type="text" id="Noodles"  value="" placeholder="noodles"><br>
<input type="text" id="Chicken" value="" placeholder="chicken"><br>
<input type="text" id="Beef" value="" placeholder="beef"><br>
```

Your problem was principally one of context - you were always selecting the value of `$("input")`. That selector fetches all input elements, but then `.attr()` (as per the first line of the documentation of that method at http://api.jquery.com/attr/) only ever returns the attribute value of the first matched element. So no matter which element called the "get()" method, it always read the attributes of the first one. The solution is to make use of `this`, which, in the context of an event listener, will represent the element which triggered the event.

I've also changed it slightly to use an unobtrusive event handler, which is a bit less verbose, and a cleaner separation between the code and markup.